# Notifications being erased if I get a new one from myself

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging, android-notification-bar

I have the below class that gets called whenever I receive a push notification. (works wherever though).
The issue is that, If I send a notification from another device to my mobile (lets say an iphone) I am getting the notification and it stays in the notification bar. If I do not touch it, and send another one, another one will arrive and 2 icons will now appear in the notification bar, However, the moment I send a notification from my own mobile to myself, all the current notifications that are in the bar disappear and get replaced by mine. When I send a new one, additional icon does not appear, but rather the old one gets updated.

**How can I make each notification appear in the notification bar ? (because each one has a unique ID sent to it via the intent that does specific thing upon opening of the designated activity)**

```
private void sendNotification(String data, String id, Context ctx)
{
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent myIntent = new Intent(ctx, myActiviy.class);
myIntent.putExtra("data", data);
myIntent.putExtra("id", id);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("notification")
        .setTicker("notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(data))
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setContentText(data);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify((int) (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000), mBuilder.build());
}?
```

Comment: Try to clean your project or something, I have the same code as you and it is working now for me :/

Answer (score 0):

The procedure you are using to show notification is now depreciated. Use the following also give unique int to `mNotificationManager.notify(uniqueId, mBuilder.build()` to show seperate notifications.

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message, String notificationId) {
    int notify = Integer.valueOf(notificationId);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, ViewPost.class);
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("group_id", this.groupId.get(notificationId));
    params.putString("post_id", this.postId.get(notificationId));
    params.putString("notification", "notification");
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    resultIntent.putExtras(params);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ViewPost.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(notify,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentTitle("FleeGroups Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(message))
        .setContentText(message)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notify, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadAamirALi , are you sure they are deprecated ? And are you sure your code solves my issue ? the way I see it, its almost the same code..

Comment: @Carnal The only difference is the TaskStackTrace, tony just pass the unique id to mNotificationManager.notify() mehtod. Your problem will be solved

Comment: @MuhammadAamirALi I am already doing that hence the System.currentTimeMillis()/1000

Comment: @tony9099 I don't see why your code should erase all other notifications. Sure, you're not calling cancelAll() or cancel(id) somewhere?

Comment: @tony9099, if your "id" that you pass in your method is unique, you could try and use that. Otherwise, create a instance variable "notifyId" and do notifyId++ before calling notify() and see if that works.

Comment: @Carnal no I am not calling cancelAll() nor cancel(id).. As I told you, this behavior happens only when I send a notification from my device to my device... I checked via the logs, and each ID is unique..

Comment: @tony9099 Try to replace PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT with 0

Comment: @tony9099 I saw this now in my app too, same problem as you. I'll look into this and see if I find a solution!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36310/discussion-between-tony9099-and-carnal)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this for id:
int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

It maybe that the two notifications were sent one after the other so the /1000 is making it resolve to the same number.

Comment: did so. same result :/ very unpredictable behaviour

Comment: Do you sometimes have multiple notifications, or is it always only 1 in the top bar.

Comment: No I do get multiple ones for sure If my app is not visible. but if it is visible, things go awry and random stuff happen...